# how to convert English number to Chinese in IOS?

Tags: swift, numberformatter

Here, This is the code of Converting English Number to Chinese Number. But I am not able to do it.

```
func convertEnglishNumberToChinese() {

    let NumberString = "100"
    let Formatter = NumberFormatter()
    let locale: NSLocale? = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "zh_Hans_CN")
    Formatter.locale = locale as Locale!
    let newNum = Formatter.number(from: NumberString)
    if newNum != nil {
        print("\(newNum)")
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know English numbers are used a lot in Chinese since their own positional numbers are rather long to write. You will have to do any conversion by yourself.

Comment: Here is a converter that I wrote. https://github.com/Sweeper777/Cheque-Helper/blob/master/Cheque%20Helper/ChineseChequeConverter.swift  It converts to cheque format though. It should be easy to change it to normal format if you know Chinese. For example, 壹 -> 一.

Comment: FYI - the code in this question is not converting English numbers to Chinese numbers. It only attempts to convert a string to a number. It then prints that number which will always be shown in English do to the use of `print` and string interpolation. What you want is to convert a number to a string using whatever locale you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let value: NSNumber = 100.02
let userLocale = Locale(identifier: "zh_Hans_CN")
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
formatter.locale = userLocale
print(formatter.string(from: value)!)
```

In my knowledge, this is the only option to convert. // .spellout number style.

You will get an output like this
一百点〇二

Comment: FYI - change `value` to: `let value = 100.02`. Then change the last line to `print(formatter.string(for: value)!)`.